# UserLocation object conversion missing in directory API

Tags: c#, json.net, google-directory-api

.NET / Google directory API

I'm working with a few of the attributes in the directory API.

On phones, for example, I can do something like this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList <Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserPhone> phone = results.Phones
```

And I'll get a list of phone numbers associated with the user. So this works along with all of the other objects thus far that I'm working with until I came across "location" which appears to be "UserLocation" in the directory API. I did verify that the object looks like matches the location json when I call getUser().

This line:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList<Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserLocation> loc = results.Locations;
```

is not valid / does not compile:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'."

When I inspect the results from getUser in the API, this field doesn't have a type like the rest of the fields (eg phone), it's a generic  `"object {Newtonsoft.JSon.linq.JArray}"`

No big deal, I tried to manually convert the JSON array using this: (implicitly typed so I'm ensuring I've got the right object)
    System.Collections.Generic.IList location = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results.Locations.ToString());

This also does not compile:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserLocation' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I didn't see multiple locations in the google admin panel so I thought it may be misreporting as an array so I tried this line:

```
Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserLocation location = (Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserLocation)results.Locations;
```

Which compiles ok / no errors or warnings.  But when run I get:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to type
>   Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserLocation;'

First, this looks like a bug in the Google .Net API and I'll be opening a bug ticket on it.  But I need to get past this now for the short term.  How can I convert this object to the UserLocation[] type?

Comment: Just a little tip for you, you can use a using statement instead of writing System.Collections.Generic everytime, if for some dumb reason you have an ambigious name you can alias the types

Comment: Yes, when I was working through the issue I strongly typed the object to ensure I was using the same object for deserialization ( which I mentioned that it's not necessary).  Normally I don't do this, but I was using it in trying to eliminate all possible issues.... But you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, this is the method that works to deserialize the object into an iList (strongly typed but not necessary to do so):

```
IList<Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserLocation> location = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.UserLocation>>(results.Locations.ToString());
```